# Most efficient way to pull first non-whitespace line from NSTextView?

Tags: cocoa, nsstring, nstextview

What is the most efficient way to pull the first non-whitespace line from an NSTextView?

For example, if the text is:

```
\n
\n
    \n
         This is the text I want     \n
 \n
Foo bar  \n
\n
```

The result would be "This is the text I want".

Here is what I have:

```
NSString *content = self.textView.textStorage.string;
NSInteger len = [content length];
NSInteger i = 0;

// Scan past leading whitespace and newlines
while (i < len && [[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[content characterAtIndex:i]]) {
    i++;
}
// Now, scan to first newline
while (i < len && ![[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[content characterAtIndex:i]]) {
    i++;
}
// Grab the substring up to that newline
NSString *resultWithWhitespace = [content substringToIndex:i];
// Trim leading and trailing whitespace/newlines from the substring
NSString *result = [resultWithWhitespace stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Is there a better, more efficient way?

I'm thinking of putting this in the -textStorageDidProcessEditing: NSTextStorageDelegate method so I can get it as the text is edited. That's why I'd like the method to be as efficient as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `NSScanner` which is designed for this sort of thing:

```
NSString* output = nil;
NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:yourString];
[scanner scanCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet] intoString:NULL];
[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet] intoString:&output];
output = [output stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Note that it's much faster if you can scan up to a particular character rather than a character set:

```
[scanner scanUpToString:@"\n" intoString:&output];
```

Comment: Thank you, Rob. This is neat. Is this faster than going char by char? Is it costly to create an NSScanner object each time the textview is edited?

Comment: `NSScanner` is pretty highly optimised and will definitely be faster than your code. Object creation overhead is too small to worry about. Whether it's fast enough depends on how much text is in your text view really. Why not profile both methods and see for yourself which one is faster?

Comment: In terms of performance, I use `NSScanner` to run multiple passes over the content of an `NSTextView` searching for various tokens at each change in the text, in order to implement syntax colouring. It's absolutely fast enough for that.

Comment: Thanks for following up, Rob. Very helpful.